# Ergodicity of differentiated processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, stochastic-filtering

Let $S$ be a vector space, and $X$ a jointly-measurable random process/field with two parameters:
$$ X: [0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\times\Omega\to S,$$
i.e. $X_{t,\theta}:\Omega\to S$ are random elements in $S$. We think of $t$ as the time parameter and $\theta$ some other parameter. Now suppose that $X$ is continuous in $t$ and $\theta$ and continuously differentiable in $\theta$ for all $t\geq 0$ and almost all $\omega\in\Omega$, such that 
$$ Y_{t,\theta}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}X_{t,\theta}$$
is defined a.s. as a random variable with values in the space $L(\mathbb{R},S)$ of linear maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $S$.
Suppose further that for all $\theta,\theta'\in\mathbb{R}$, the process 
$$ \xi_{t,\theta,\theta'} = (X_{t,\theta},X_{t,\theta'})$$
has a unique invariant probability measure $\mu_{\theta,\theta'}$ over $S\times S$ such that we have a strong law of large numbers
$$\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tF(\xi_{\theta,\theta',s})ds\to\mu_{\theta,\theta'}F\quad\text{a.s.},\quad t\to\infty.$$
**Question:** Do we then have that also the process 
$$\psi_{\theta,t}=(X_{t,\theta},Y_{t,\theta})$$
has a unique invariant probability measure $\tilde\mu_{\theta}$ over $S\times L(\mathbb{R},S)$ such that
$$\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tG(\psi_{\theta,s})ds\to\tilde\mu_{\theta}G\quad\text{a.s.},\quad t\to\infty?$$

The question arose in a filter stability/ergodicity problem related to parameter estimation.